# How can I compress multiple files using glib.zlibcompressor in vala?

Tags: compression, glib, vala

I have seen the example in valadoc.com for one file, but is any way to compress a list of files into only compressed package?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GZip does not support doing that. You probably want to make a tar archive which is then compressed with gzip. In that case, use [libarchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples), for which there are Vala bindings.